# Change UIButton size programmatically in dialog in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, dialog, uibutton

I create dialog with custom button UIButton in swift IOS. How can change UIButton size programmatically.

```
class SuccessMessageView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

private var buttonConfirm : UIButton = {
    
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Ok", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: PreferenceManager.shared.hasDevice() ? purpleColour : orangeColour)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(confirmFunc), for: .touchDown)
    
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140.0).isActive = true
    button.frame.size.width = 140
    return button
}
}
```

Comment: you have already edited its size by setting `widthAnchor` and `frame`

Comment: Hi @widthAnchor It not effected size with edit value.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this? Just remove the frame-related lines.

```
private lazy var buttonConfirm : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Ok", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(confirmFunc), for: .touchUpInside)

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    return button
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 fileprivate func Frame() -> CGRect {
        var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2, height: 2)
        return circleFrame
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for set UIButton width and height programatically like that set with constant.

```
button.anchor(nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 20, heightConstant: 30)
    button.anchorCenterXToSuperview()
```